# Which questions should have tag grammar?

Tags: discussion

Which questions should be asked under a tag [`grammar`](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar)?

Should those questions be only about formal grammar of programming languages (which are used in EVM for smart contracts for example) or should this tag be used both for questions about formal grammar and for questions about English grammar covering spelling of particular terms used in documentation or related to blockchain?

Answer (score 5):

I would say that questions regarding English grammar are off-topic.  The [grammar](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) should be used for formal grammar within an Ethereum context.

Of the four questions with this tag at present, only one is not for formal grammar.  Even that is about the correct plural of *Ether*, which is arguably not English grammar either.

At present, the tag has no usage guidance wiki.  Perhaps one should be created.